# swiftの型指定で[]の意味は？

Tags: swift

swiftでwebviewのCookie情報の取得サンプルで以下のコードを見つけました。

```
let cookies:[NSHTTPCookie] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]
for cookie:NSHTTPCookie in cookies as [NSHTTPCookie] {
    if cookie.name as String == "CookieName" {
        let cookieValue : String = "CookieName=" + cookie.value as String
        NSLog(cookieValue)
    }
}
```

[NSHTTPCookie]はNSHTTPCookieのclassだと思いますが、[]の意味(使用用途)は何でしょうか？
Swift関連の本を確認してもわからなかったのでご存知であればお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

配列です。

`[NSHTTPCookie]` は `Array<NSHTTPCookie>` と全く同じ意味になります。